# German Letters encoding problem

Tags: c#, encoding, character-encoding

I get HTML from a webpage that is in german language, i have to insert its html in database, but when I insert it in database the german letters does not appear coorectly. 
E.g. `Bundesstraße` appears as `Bundesstra&#223;e`. I am using C# and MYsql database.

Comment: There is not difference between the two example values. Can you edit this to make it more clear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like special characters are encoded as html entities (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp) on the website. When using UTF8 this isn't necessary, but many sites still do it.

If you want to have the exact html as it is on the website these encoded entities are correct.
To decode the entities you can use `System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(yourString)`.

Comment: That's the same. With `System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(yourString)` you just don't have to add a reference to System.Web.dll.

Answer (score 1):

What encoding are you using?

Try switching to UTF-8 and ensure your database supports it. It looks as if though your string is getting HTML encoding, this is fine for presentation, but you'll need the original format to store it in the database.

Comment: I am using the datatype "utf8_general_ci" in mysql

Answer (score 0):

In HTML, `ß` is encoded as `&#223;`.

You say "i have to insert its html in database", and what you're currently getting is correct.